Using PSpell On Shared Hosting Environment "en" Dictionary Not Found
I'm on a shared hosting environment and trying to get a basic pspell to run with PHP.
When I put this code:
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  @ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  $pSpell = pspell_new("en");
  if (pspell_check($pSpell, "and")) {
    echo "Good";
  } else {
    echo "Bad";
  }
?>

I always receive "Bad" no matter what word I put in, and there's a warning that I've found as follows:
Warning: pspell_new(): PSPELL couldn't open the dictionary. reason: No word lists can be found for the language "en".

Most of the questions I can find online are assuming shell access or that pspell is already fully working.
So my questions are as follows:
(1) Is it possible to do something to upload a custom dictionary and get pspell to use that dictionary from a shared hosting environment?
(2) What specifically should I be asking from my shared hosting provider to get this main dictionary working?
I appreciate any help. Thanks again.
